# Laravel get data from another project database

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm moving the old project database to a new project database. the structure of the old project database is a single MYSQL database and the new project is the multi-tenant database which contained a lot of subdomains. Also, the new project already set up a RESTFUL API to receive the data from the old project. Therefore, my idea is to implement the multi-connection in the new project in order to link both databases together then get data from the old project. Example, the new project `sales` table is an empty and old project `sales` table already contains some data. Now in my new project interface maybe have a sync button in order to move data from the old database into a new database. Do I need to pass the API key before sending data into a new project? Since it's a multi-tenant structure.

This is my config/database

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'aurora-2016-cluster.cluster-rtygfdfg.ap-southwest-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
            'database'  => 'newProject',
            'username'  => @$_ENV['DB_USER'] ?: '',
            'password'  => @$_ENV['DB_PASS'] ?: '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'oldProject',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its Quite Simple in laravel open your `config/databse.php` file

you will find the code like this

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Steps to be followed

Step1:
Adding new arry to databse connection array

```
'mysqlSecondConnection' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST1', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT1', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'secondDatabseName'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'secondDatabseUserName'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', 'secondDatabsePassword'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET2', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

After this your file may look like

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'mysqlSecondConnection' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST1', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT1', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'secondDatabseName'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'secondDatabseUserName'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', 'secondDatabsePassword'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET2', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],


        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Step2: Configure Your Database name in `mysqlSecondConnection` array

**`IF THIS PROJECT IS TEAM COLLABRATING DONT FORGET TO ADD THE NEW ATTRIBUTES IN .ENV FILE`**

Step 3:
Now we are finished configuring the databse

Step 4:
Open you Model that need to interacts with the `mysqlSecondConnection` Database

And add the

Property

```
protected $connection ='mysqlSecondConnection';
```

After this the mode may look like For Eg: 
I am Considering it as `Post.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
/**
 * Class Cat
 *
 * @package App
*/

class Post extends Model
{


    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection ='mysqlSecondConnection';

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

     /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'int';



    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name','title','desc'];

     /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];


}
```

Thats its

Now the testing part

Open your web.php file inside route folder

and paste the following code

```
Route::get('/testSecondConnection', function () 
{
    $posts= App\Post::all();
    dd($posts);

});
```

Now navigate to `yourApplication/testSecondConnection`

now see the `connection` property in the dumped

EDITED

I actually Forget to add another method that is via `DB` Facade version

Just pass the connection name to the `DB`  inside the `connection` method

While using this this does not check for model

for the `$connection` Property in `Post` Model

```
$dbVersion = \DB::connection('mysqlSecondConnection')->table('posts')->get();
dd($dbVersion);
```

Edited for `But which method is more efficient?`

Good question Mate

Situation 1:

For Eg:

If You are Using the `mysqlSecondConnection` for the `Post` model in all the situation of your project then 
add this to Your model

```
protected $connection ='mysqlSecondConnection';
```

and this is good and 
NOTE `$connection`  Property Will work on `Eloquent` not in `DB` Facade

Situation 2:

`Eg:'

if you are using only few Queries and calls to that `mysqlSecondConnection`

You Dont need to add

`protected $connection ='mysqlSecondConnection';`

`Post` Model

```
DB Facade Version 

$dbVersion = \DB::connection('mysqlSecondConnection')->table('posts')->get();
    dd($dbVersion);

Eloquent Version

$eloquentVersion = Post::on('mysqlSecondConnection')->get()
    dd($eloquentVersion);
```

YOU MAY GET THE DOUBT WHY DB FACADE IS NOT USING `mysqlSecondConnection` IN POST MODEL

Solution:

While using the `DB` FACADE

It Will look into the `config/datbase.php`

for `default` array

Which is used in connection to database

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

Hope its helps and look clear

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which mean I could use either `Model` or `DB::connection` to get the `posts` data? But which method is more efficient?