# How to connect with another database to submiit the data in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a cms project. I was created a portal and thenn new database connection created. So,there is a table users i wan that if someone create new user in that portal then it will be added to the master database that is another database. So, in laravel how can we make connection with another database and save the data of the portal to our master database table also.

Trying to make a sync connection that if in cms portal if admin create a user then that data must be submitted to the master table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel get data from another project database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288815/laravel-get-data-from-another-project-database)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

**In .env add the following:** note that you can customize your connection to another database, like postgres/mariadb etc.. check the documentation here for supported databases: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#introduction

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=localhost
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=db2
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=user2
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=password2
```

**In config/database.php**: note that you can customize your connection to another database, like postgres/mariadb etc.. check the documentation here for supported databases: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#introduction

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

**In the sample model:**

```
class Job extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
}
```